# How to make a menu that doesnt pause my program when used?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, winapi, opengl, menu

This is my code for creating my menu for the program:

```
WNDCLASS wc;
...
hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProc;
wc.hInstance = hInstance;
...
if(!RegisterClass(&wc)) ...
```

Now if i open the menu, my program will pause until i dont use the menu anymore, how do i make it so my window would keep rendering even if i use the menu? I am using OpenGL window, if that matters.

Note that the menu should render exactly like it does with this code (so it would not render the menu OVER my opengl render area, but take space for its own area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do your rendering in a separate thread - popping up a menu will always halt  a single-threaded Windows application.

Comment: so.. do you have any answer to solve this problem then? how do i make it into a thread etc

Comment: @Rookie That would require a book. Or two,  or three.

Comment: @Rookie The answer is to run your rendering in a different thread from the UI.

Comment: & @david, is there any winapi solution, like using CreateWindow or something? the statusbar im already using kinda creates new thread and it runs independently from my program (i think, because it can display my menu selection tips there).

Comment: @Rookie No, the status bar doesn't run in a separate thread. and there is no real way of doing what you want without creating one. Theoretically, you can get by with only using Windows messages, but this is almost impossibly difficult to get right - threading is actually much easier.